# An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am getting this error (Please check screenshot)

How can i solve this

Please help.

Thanks [image]

Comment: Check your Internet Connnection once.

Comment: @Tristup my internet is working good.

Comment: What is the environment? Are working in local? Are you using xampp / Wamp? What is OS??

Answer (score 0):

You may debug this issue by enabling WP_DEBUG from wp-config.php file and share us the response of it.

Ref: https://www.technobezz.com/topics/threads/notice-has_cap-was-called-with-an-argument-that-is-deprecated.457/

More precisely as per the error you may do the following:

Also, find the plugin that is causing the problem. by deactivating all of them one by one.

when you find the culprit

go to your root folder >wp-content>plugins> the culprit plugin
open the Plugin php file with an editor, Notepad ++

look for “add_options_page”
in my case you will see in the same line

```
add_options_page(“Popular Tags Options”, “Popular Tags”, 8, basename(__FILE__), “ads_admin_page_inc”);
```

remove the “8”
and put ‘activate_plugins’

so it will be

```
add_options_page(“Popular Tags Options”, “Popular Tags”, ‘activate_plugins’, basename(__FILE__), “ads_admin_page_inc”);
```

with single colon

Comment: How can i do that ?

Comment: Locate the wp-config.php file from your root directory, Edit the wp-config.php file as define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); and save the file. and refresh your page.

Comment: Notice: has_cap was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.0.0! Usage of user levels is deprecated. Use capabilities instead. in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-wosb\wp-includes\functions.php on line 4032

I am getting this error

Comment: [https://wordpress.org/support/topic/has_cap-was-called-with-an-argument/](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/has_cap-was-called-with-an-argument/) This link might add some help